# How to print the const in html tag in react js?

Tags: html, reactjs, local-storage

I have a localstorage value in const i need to use in html tag.How to do so?

My js code is:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const userName = localStorage.getItem('userName');
  console.log(userName);

}
```

My Html code where i need to use is:

```
<Dropdown.Toggle className="nav-link count-indicator bg-transparent">
                  <span className="profile-text"></span>
                  userName here
                </Dropdown.Toggle>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render any dynamic value by wrapping the value using `{}` in JSX

```
<Dropdown.Toggle className="nav-link count-indicator bg-transparent">
   <span className="profile-text"></span>{localStorage.getItem('userName');} 
</Dropdown.Toggle>
```

Or if that value is dynamic and if component should rerender when the value changes you can store it in a `state`

like

```
 export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    username: ""
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    localStorage.setItem("username", "TEST USERNAME");
    this.setState({ username: localStorage.getItem("username") });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    localStorage.removeItem("username");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <h1>Username from state is {this.state.username}</h1>
        <h1>
          Username directly from localStorage {localStorage.getItem("username")}
        </h1>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Please find the working code sandbox in [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-waterfall-qurvq) link

Comment: No,its not rendering i think need to do something like this.userName like that but i don't know the exact method.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to define the `userName` in your state, so that you can assign a value to it in `componentDidmount`. Then you can use it like this -

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      userName: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({userName: localStorage.getItem('userName')})
    console.log(userName);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Dropdown.Toggle className="nav-link count-indicator bg-transparent">
        <span className="profile-text"></span>
        {this.state.userName}
      </Dropdown.Toggle>
    );
  }
}
```